# Why doesn't dropna seem to work on this column?

Tags: python, pandas, na

I try to drop all na values in one column `Filmname`, but the values don't get dropped. Why? (screenshot of my result)

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = read.csv....

df.dropna(subset=['Filmname'], inplace=True)
df.head()
```

Comment: To me it LOOKS like the Filmnames are strings 'na', not actual pandas NaNs

Comment: So an alternative in that case is `df = df[df.Filmname != 'na'] `

Answer (score 3):

By default, "na" is not considered `NaN` by `pandas.read_csv`.

You can add this as a `NaN` string manually via the `na_values` argument:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', na_values=['na'])
```

As per the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html):

> **na_values** : scalar, str, list-like, or dict, default None
>
> Additional strings to recognize as NA/NaN. If dict passed, specific
>   per-column NA values. By default the following values are interpreted
>   as NaN: ‘’, ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’,
>   ‘-nan’, ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘n/a’, ‘nan’,
>   ‘null’.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what your values are in this screenshot is not "NaN" or some real error, but a parsed string of the value "na".

In order to filter out the rows with this value in this column, you can use to simply refer to the df with a condition, instead of using dropna:

```
df = pd.read_csv(...)
filtered_df = df[df['Filmname'] != 'na']
```

The condition inside may be anything, see [this guide](https://chrisalbon.com/python/data_wrangling/pandas_selecting_rows_on_conditions/) for a start

Comment: This may not be the best idea. Because there may also be genuine `NaN` values, which will then need to be treated separately.

Comment: Yes you want to logical-or this condition with whether the value is `NaN`